# Why is this statement in a Java programming code invalid?

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, command-line-arguments

```
args[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

*Note:* Yes, I'm converting an array of String data type to integer type values and storing it to the same array. But, this efficient code result in an error, why? Is it because the entire array is marked as String while it's being converted which is why it is an error, or?

Comment: args is of type String[]. You cannot assign type Integer into type String.

Comment: I don't think this is *efficient code*.

Comment: So this must be the most answers i've seen so quickly in a very long time

Answer (score 8):

It's probably easiest to demonstrate it without using `parseInt`:

```
String[] x = new String[5];
x[0] = 100;
```

Would you expect that to compile? It won't because you're trying to assign an `int` into a `String` array element.

Or we could get rid of the array part, too:

```
String x = 100;
```

Would you expect *that* to compile? If not, why do you think the array version is different? And if you don't think the array version is different (i.e. it shouldn't compile) what significant difference do you see between my examples and your code?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are assigning an `int` to a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't store an `int` in a `String[]`.  Don't use the same array.

You may think this is "efficient," but the number of bytes used to store a `String` reference in the array might be different from the number of bytes used to store an `int` -- it doesn't necessarily even make sense to use the same array at a memory level, let alone the loss of type safety.

Comment: He is storing `int` in `String`, not `String[]`

Comment: @BackSlash. He is storing an `int` in a `String[]` actually.

Comment: @BackSlash. `args` is an array. So he is inserting an `int` in that array at index `i`.

Comment: By "*in* a `String[]`, I mean "as an element of a `String[]`".  You mean storing an `int` _as_ a `String[]`, which is not what I said.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, but he's not doing `args = Integer.parseInt(args[i])`, he's doing `args[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i])`. The integer is being assigned to a `String`, not to the array.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, to me it sounded like _you are storing an integer value to an array_ (which is illegal to, but it's not that case)

Comment: @BackSlash I guess you understood *you can't store an `int` in a `String[]` **variable***

Comment: Jon, please come here and give the verdict!

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't make any sense.  You are parsing the `String` argument into an `int`, but you're attempting to assign it back to a `String` in the `String[]` array.  You can't assign an `int` to a `String`.

Sure, you can convert it back to a `String` to assign it back to a position in the array, but there's no reason for that; you already had the `String` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(args[i])` returns an `int` and you are trying to assign it to a `String` array element.

Answer (score 0):

```
int integerArgs[] = new int[args.length];

...

integerArgs[i] Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As everybody explained It is not possible to convert int(primitive) to String(object) i.e You can't assign the int value to a String Type one

**So Why this conversion is not Possible means Why it is not allowed In java?**

```
it is because Strings are objects and they are not primitives like int.
```

Example code to show why the language does not allow this casting i.e between primitive to object

```
  class Student
  {
     int sid;  // student id no of type "int"

     String name;  // name which is of type "String"
  }
```

Suppose "sri" is an object instantiated from Student class

```
sri = (Student)10;
```

> When you doing this it is not clear to the language what it would mean to cast from  int(primitive) to String(object) i.e Should the language set his sid or name to 10? since it is not clear while you doing this casting from int to object, language did not allowed it
>
> objects are too general So that you cannot cast it from int(primitives) to an object.